# Poor font rendering in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am running R on void linux. The font rendering on my output graph is poor quality despite specifying high resolution in my ggplot2 argument.
Surprisingly pdf output is good quality. But png & jpeg fail.
Earlier I used Ubuntu linux and it had excellent graph quality.

Comment: Is there are question about programming in this post?

Comment: No, i am looking forward to fix graph quality.

Comment: Have you tried different graphic devices? For example; https://github.com/r-lib/ragg

Comment: Update: when I save using 'ggsave(filename="file.png", type="cairo-png")' the output is good quality. I think it has to do with cairo device. How can I get this behaviour with regular use of ggplot command. Is there a way to set cairo as default device.